# URL Link inside app to self in app store

Tags: ios, itunes, publish

Not sure how to write title any more accurately but I guess it does say what I'm after. I have an app that has not yet been published. The app has a functionality which prompts user to rate the app after the fifth launch. I am not sure how to open up iTunes and link to that app if I don't know the URL yet.

There must be some kind of a work around right? :) Some kind of ID or something like that? Or must I really wait for the first publish and then copy the url and update the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to iTunesConnect and click on your app, there will be an App Store Link that you can  use, even if it is not published yet.